# setTextAppearance causes android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-studio

Alright so I'm working on Android Studio 0.8.14 with API 15-20

I have a `TextView tvInitials`, and I've initialized, and set it up like this

## AvatarView.java

```java
tvInitials = new TextView(context);
tvInitials.setLayoutParams(params);
tvInitials.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tvInitials.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.post_avatar_bg);
tvInitials.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.someStyle);   //<Problematic line
```

## styles.xml

```xml
<style name="someStyle">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
</style>
```

but my layout viewer in android studio is giving me this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:484)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2484)
    at com.vvminovv.bugtest.view.AvatarView.init(AvatarView.java:57)
    at com.vvminovv.bugtest.view.AvatarView.<init>(AvatarView.java:35)
    ____MORE WHERE THIS CAME FROM, ASK FOR IT IF IT HELPS____
```

But if I run the app on my phone it seems to work perfectly fine. The problem is only in the layout viewer in both the `Design` and `Text` tabs.

If I remove the problematic line:

`tvInitials.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.someStyle);` the layout doesn't give me the error anymore (but obviously doesn't style it either)

Just to do a sanity check, I checked if there was something wrong with the style so I added it to one of the textViews that were in my layout like so:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    style="@style/someStyle"/>
```

and that work perfectly. So I'm just having trouble applying the style dynamically.

---

I've also found that if I try to do it in the constructor in `AvatarView.java` like this:

## AvatarView.java

```java
tvInitials = new TextView(context, null, R.style.someStyle);    //<Changed the constructor
tvInitials.setLayoutParams(params);
tvInitials.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tvInitials.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.post_avatar_bg);
//tvInitials.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.someStyle); //<Problematic line
```

The layout viewer gives a different error:
`Failed to find style 'someStyle' in current theme`, and it also fails to render correctly on Android, so we've eliminated that as an option.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: I posted it over at the android open source project here and they seem to have planned a fix for it in a `FutureRelease`

The link is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78842&thanks=78842&ts=1415300350)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with the dev team, and they marked it as a bug in the interface.

Check info [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78842&thanks=78842&ts=1415300350)

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue and solved through removing the textAppearance statement from the xml layout file, this bug is in 2.3.3 version also